# Почему ассинхронные данные получаемые get запросом не отображаются в React приложении?

Tags: reactjs, golang, mongodb

Я делаю простой todolist по туториалу
https://levelup.gitconnected.com/build-a-todo-app-in-golang-mongodb-and-react-e1357b4690a6
Здесь github по реакту в этом приложении
https://github.com/schadokar/go-to-do-app/tree/master/client/src

и я не могу понять, почему не отображаются данные получаемые get запросом в React приложении
[image: Мое приложении выглядит вот так, когда данные должны были отобразится]

```
 getTask = () => {
    axios.get(endpoint + "/api/task").then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        if (res.data) {
            this.setState({
                items: res.data.map(item => {
                    let color = "yellow";

                    if (item.status) {
                        color = "green";
                    }
                    return (
                        <Card key={item._id} color={color} fluid>
                            <Card.Content>
                                <Card.Header textAlign="left">
                                    <div style={{ wordWrap: "break-word" }}>{item.task}</div>
                                </Card.Header>

                                <Card.Meta textAlign="right">
                                    <Icon
                                        name="check circle"
                                        color="green"
                                        onClick={() => this.updateTask(item._id)}
                                    />
                                    <span style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}>Done</span>
                                    <Icon
                                        name="undo"
                                        color="yellow"
                                        onClick={() => this.undoTask(item._id)}
                                    />
                                    <span style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}>Undo</span>
                                    <Icon
                                        name="delete"
                                        color="red"
                                        onClick={() => this.deleteTask(item._id)}
                                    />
                                    <span style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}>Delete</span>
                                </Card.Meta>
                            </Card.Content>
                        </Card>
                    );
                })
            });
        } else {
            this.setState({
                items: []
            });
        }
    });
};
```

[image: Сервер работает]

Comment: Проверьте, точно ли вы получаете данные

Comment: из сервера, да, я проверял через postman

Comment: покажите код запроса, пожалуйста

Comment: покажите  console.log(res);

Comment: console.log(res) ничего не выводи на консоль, не понимаю почему

Comment: Что хранит в себе endpoint?

Comment: let endpoint = "http://localhost:8080";

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в Backend на Go , дело в том, что там была ошибка Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/task' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
и я ее исправил в коде , там была буква l лишняя в func GetAllTask(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request), спасибо за помощь.